# jQuery dialog Title Icon Work Around Causes Other Options to be Ignored

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I hope this isn't wasting anyone's time... I've been researching and trying different solutions for hours now and cannot get this to work.

I am using jQuery UI 1.10.1.  I want to add an icon to the title.  The following code does not work with version 1.10.1:

```
$("#dialog").dialog(
{
    title: '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home"></span> Example Dialog'
});
```

So, I'm using the following code as a work around:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
            {
                var eventDialog = $("#createEventForm").dialog();

                eventDialog.data("uiDialog")._title = function(title) 
                {
                    title.html(this.options.title);
                };

                eventDialog.dialog(
                {
                    title: "<span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-pencil\" style=\"float: left; margin-right: 4px;\"></span> New Appointment",
                    modal: true,
                    autoOpen: false,
                    width: "auto",
                    buttons: [
                    {
                        text: "Save",
                        'click': function()
                        {
                            // do something with .ajax in here
                        },
                        icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-plus'}
                    },
                    {
                        text: "Cancel",
                        'click': function()
                        {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        },
                        icons: {primary: 'ui-icon-cancel'}
                    }]
                });
            });
</script>
```

Now the icon is in the title bar like I want, but the 'modal' and 'autoOpen' options are being ignored.  The 'width' and 'buttons' options are working as expected.

Actually, they are only ignored when the page loads.  If I close the dialog and then click the button that triggers it in my html, all options have their expected effects when the dialog opens again.